# Do we have XQuery abort() function

Tags: xquery, basex

Do we have an abort() function to terminate a XQuery script from XQuery 3.1? I can write a if-else to return nothing. But I dont want to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`error(...)`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-error) function for that. The thrown error can then be caught by `try`/`catch` if needed. Using errors for control flow is not advisable however, because it is normally not optimized for performance.